# check if output parameter is null before binding

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How can i check if an output parameter is null before i bind it to a asp literal, and if it is null i want to just make the literal

```
hname1.Text = cmd.Parameters("@hotel1").Value
            hname1.DataBind()

            hname2.Text = cmd.Parameters("@hotel2").Value
            hname2.DataBind()

            hname3.Text = cmd.Parameters("@hotel3").Value
            hname3.DataBind()

            hname4.Text = cmd.Parameters("@hotel4").Value
            hname4.DataBind()

            hname5.Text = cmd.Parameters("@hotel5").Value
            hname5.DataBind()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If Not IsDBNull(cmd.Parameters("@hotel1").Value) Then
  hname1.Text = cmd.Parameters("@hotel1").Value
  hname1.DataBind();
Else
  ' Manual binding would go here
End If
```

I believe. Syntax may be a bit hairy as it's been a bit since I've done VB, but the premise should be the same.

This is also assuming `cmd.Parameters("@hotel1")` will always be a callable object with a `Value` property. If this could potentially be null, we need to add another comparison to avoid NullObjectReference exception(s).

Also, I hope I understand the question correctly, your mention of "output parameter" without having a Subroutine/Function to look at leads me to believe there's a bit of confusion on semantics.

**Version Change**

- Using [IsDBNull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tckcces5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to check against empty value

Comment: Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid.

Comment: that is the error i am trying to avoid but i still get it after making this change : /

Comment: Ah ha, I have [just the solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tckcces5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: If you use c# instead of VB, the equivalent check is: if (cmd.Parameters("@hotel1").Value != System.DBNull.Value)